# difference between a DNS zone and DNS domain

Tags: networking, dns, network-programming, tcp

I am confused between two DNS notions.
My question is  what is the difference between a "DNS zone" and a "DNS domain"?

thanks

Comment: I've also posted an answer [here](https://serverfault.com/a/1082778/519099) on ServerFault.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

As explained [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/164054):

> Domain name servers store information about part of the domain name
>   space called a zone. The name server is authoritative for a particular
>   zone. A single name server can be authoritative for many zones.
>
> Understanding the difference between a zone and a domain is sometimes
>   confusing. A zone is simply a portion of a domain. For example, the
>   Domain Microsoft.com may contain all of the data for Microsoft.com,
>   Marketing.microsoft.com and Development.microsoft.com. However, the
>   zone Microsoft.com contains only information for Microsoft.com and
>   references to the authoritative name servers for the subdomains.
>
> The zone Microsoft.com can contain the data for subdomains of
>   Microsoft.com if they have not been delegated to another server. For
>   example, Marketing.microsoft.com may manage its own delegated zone.
>   Development.microsoft.com may be managed by the parent, Microsoft.com.
>
> If there are no subdomains, then the zone and domain are essentially
>   the same. In this case the zone contains all data for the domain.

More details are available [here](https://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=windowsserver&seqNum=281) and [here](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/net_mgmt/prime/network_registrar/8-1/user/guide/CPNR_8_1_User_Guide/UG15_DNS.pdf/index.html).

Comment: the cisco link has expired.....

Comment: Updated. Thanks.

Comment: All links are dead

Comment: All links broken, and the excerpt you used is not particularly helpful...

Comment: @Watki02 You're more than welcome to add a more helpful answer.

Comment: @VladSchnakovszki, actually I can't - the question is closed as off-topic :-). I *am* considering writing up my own Question and Answer in Server Fault.

Comment: @Watki2 Go for it and you can link it here in the comments.

Comment: https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/dns/glossary/dns-zone/ explains well.